# Facebook PHP SDK unable to upload more then one image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am running into a problem with uploading pictures to the users album on Facebook using the latest Facebook PHP SDK.  I am able to upload one picture, but after the first one, it will not let me upload a second image (i've tried this using the same picture as the first one as well as a completely different image).

I assume it is not an authentication problem since I am able to upload the first image and after checking what the user is authenticated for, I get the following:

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [installed] => 1
            [status_update] => 1
            [photo_upload] => 1
            [video_upload] => 1
            [email] => 1
            [create_note] => 1
            [share_item] => 1
            [publish_stream] => 1
            [publish_actions] => 1
            [user_likes] => 1
            [user_photos] => 1
         )
    )
)
```

Here is the code I am currently using to upload my image:

```
<?php
    $mee = $facebook->api('/me');
    //echo $mee['name']; // test to make sure FB is connected
    $item = '202';
    $filename = 'bc2a846f1bfafa8d811390089a91bcfa.jpeg';

    $qry = "SELECT albumID FROM os_users WHERE user_fbid = '".$_SESSION['fbid']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $alb = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    // Check if Album already exists
    if($alb['albumID'] !=  '0'){
        $album_id = $alb['albumID'];
    } else {
        echo 'Creating Album';
        //Create an album
        $album_details = array(
            'message' => 'Album Message', 
            'name' => 'Album Name'
        );

        $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

        // Get album ID of the album you've just created
        $album_id = $create_album['id'];

        $qry = "UPDATE scav_users SET user_albumid = '".$album_id."' WHERE user_fbid = '".$_SESSION['ufbid']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry);
    }

    // Upload Image
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $photo_details = array(
        'message' => '#'.$item.': Item Description'
    );
    $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath('../uploads/'.$filename);

    try {
        $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e){print_r($e);}
    //$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
    $photo_id = $upload_photo['id'];
    echo $photo_id;
?>
```

The error that is a result of this script after I try to upload another picture is as follows:

```
FacebookApiException Object (
    [result:protected] => Array (
        [error] => Array (
            [message] => An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 2
        )
    )
    [message:protected] => An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
    [string:Exception:private] =>
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => [locationtofile]base_facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 1106
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [file] => [locationtofile][base_facebook.php
            [line] => 810
            [function] => throwAPIException
            [class] => BaseFacebook
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [error] => Array (
                        [message] => An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
                        [type] => OAuthException
                        [code] => 2
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [function] => _graph
            [class] => BaseFacebook
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array (
                [0] => //photos
                [1] => post
                [2] => Array (
                    [message] => #202: Item Description
                    [image] => @[locationtofile]bc2a846f1bfafa8d811390089a91bcfa.jpeg
                )
            )
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [file] => [locationtofile][base_facebook.php
            [line] => 587
            [function] => call_user_func_array
            [args] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [0] => Facebook Object (
                    [appId:protected] => 435146213185130
                    [appSecret:protected] => 96797309425855946b0b495f9adf6252
                    [user:protected] =>
                    [signedRequest:protected] => Array (
                        [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
                        [code] => 2.AQBPPU0myCWfUCPt.3600.1342501200.1-100003953568312|8LHGtxCV0OZZfE-826am15ODSZo
                        [issued_at] => 1342495041
                        [user_id] => 100003953568312
                    )
                    [state:protected] =>
                    [accessToken:protected] => AAAGLw192VmoBABK5rNEsnoROQHvcFuKt720JuUV2DP20llDD1Ny9NPLE2ZBVi4WIypB5n1yfodv7VBWFTrTi0dF6Ncm3PGIxDK2yCmbJPJO14xH7C
                    [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 1
                )
                [1] => _graph 
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => //photos
                [1] => post
                [2] => Array (
                    [message] => #202: Item Description
                    [image] => @[locationtofile]bc2a846f1bfafa8d811390089a91bcfa.jpeg
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [file] => [locationtofile][uploadtoFB.php
        [line] => 44
        [function] => api
        [class] => BaseFacebook
        [type] => ->
        [args] => Array (
            [0] => //photos
            [1] => post
            [2] => Array (
                [message] => #202: Item Description
                [image] => @[locationtofile]bc2a846f1bfafa8d811390089a91bcfa.jpeg
            )
        )
    )
)
[previous:Exception:private] =>
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: My application is still in its sandbox stage and I am running it on a local server.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right, you have an $session['fbid'], which is the album_id, correct? To troubleshoot I'd make that association clearer:

- query Facebook for the id (not your db)
- upon successful result (check FacebookAPIException),
- publish the next photo, to that album_id

Also, you aren't checking each api call with try/catch, that's a good practice.

I'd also not include a message until this is cleared. Facebook is known to flag publishes for that reason.

This is pretty clearly an auth issue, so also push the access_token as as a separate parameter in each api call.

Comment: FBID is actually the Facebook ID of the current user. I suppose I do not really need to make that a session now that I think about it.

I will be sure to implement your suggestions and see how that goes.  Appreciate your input

Comment: OK, one issue is there's no try/catch around the Album ID retrieval, you should do that just to be conscientious/troubleshooting. And, you shouldn't rely on your own db for it, but check each time (users can erase them). I've had albums in some odd pending state with Facebook before (which is what I suspect, here).

Comment: oh so it should be the persons_ID and not the albums_ID?  I thought it should be the albums_id (the one that I just created).  If I upload to the person's ID, it would be the same using `$facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $photo_details);` right?

Also, can you help guide me on how to push the access_token? I tried adding the parameter: `'access_token'=> $access_token` ($access_token is the users access token). I am still getting errors

Comment: In general, to keep the association and the user's experience with FB tight and fast, use FB as the "system of record" and update your own database after the fact, informationally. I see that you grab db data instead of FB in a few places, and that's open to being broken from a user's perspective. you should also check for or die(mysql_error()) on your mysql calls- it could be erroring and not telling you, and discontinuing the rest of your code.

Comment: No you're right, it's the album_id (not person id) (Just checked some of my code): `$result = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'POST',$args);`

Comment: Can you change your error to just `echo $e;` and tell me what it says?

Comment: To your question earlier, add access_token as a key/value in your `$photo_details` array: `$photo_details['access_token'] = $access_token;`

Comment: First of all, just wanted to say thank you so much for your help Anna.  I did `echo $e` and got the following `OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13977/discussion-between-anna-billstrom-and-michael-cheung)

Comment: After trying a whole bunch of stuff, the reason I could not upload more than one image ended up being because I was using Facebook's test user account.  When I switched to a live account, it began uploading images with no issue. Thanks Anna for getting me on the right path